# android service in a separate thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-activity

I have a main activity class A and a service class S in the same package, I started S when I start A. My question is: Is the run-time memory of S counted as part of A? If I force stop A, do I stop S as well? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html).

By default, all components of the application are executed in the same thread, but yo ucan change this behavior using `android:process` attribute in the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

My expirience is that S does in fact stop in such a case. But if you start S as a seperate Activity, ie. let it extend Activity (or subclass of such), then I don't know.

But yes, maybe the answer is in [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html).